# Running shell commands from bytes objects in python 3.1 (Or writing UTF-8 mp3 tags in python 3.1)

Tags: python, unicode, mp3, python-3.x

I'm writing a script which uses .CUE files to split monolithic music files into individual tracks, then encodes them in MP3 along with correct tags from the CUE. It's all working, but unfortunately the tags (applied simply through including them with `lame`'s command line arguments) reliably show up as gibberish in iTunes when they include unicode characters (Which they always do, due to the music being Japanese).

I can fix them by running them through [this](http://code.google.com/p/mp3tagiconv/) script, but that's another script to run , and occasionally attaches quote marks to the tags (A bug I have been unable to fix), requiring yet one more run of a script to remove.

So my preferred solution is to encode the `lame` command + arguments string as UTF-8 before running it, but python 3.1 appears to have no support for running commands from bytes rather than strings. Simply passing a string instead encodes incorrectly.

Alternatively, I'm happy with simply using a tagging library to insert the tags after the encoding is finished, though a solution like that is slower and less elegant. Any suggestions are welcome, though!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I invoke `lame` like this (sorry for long line):

```
args = "lame --tt \"{0}\" --tn {1:02d}  --ta \"{2}\" --tl \"{3}\"  \"{4}\" \"{5}.mp3\"".format(item.title, item.tracknumber, item.artist, albumObject.title, item.wavFile, "{0:02d} ".format(item.tracknumber) + item.title)
#args = bytearray(args, "utf-8")
retcode = subprocess.check_call(args)
```

Comment: also, it would be helpful to see how you invoke lame in your script

Comment: What system are you on--Windows, Mac, Linux? If Windows, is the "default system code page" set to Japanese?

Comment: I'm on OSX. The terminal I'm executing in is UTF-8, as default.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call()` can accept list of arguments: `args=["lame", "--tt", item.title, "--tn", "{0:02d}".format(item.tracknumber), ...]`

Comment: Thanks, that's how it was before, but then I had a bunch of weird "file not found" errors and switched to os.system. I switched it above so I wouldn't undergo the "Why are you using os.system()?" talk.

Comment: @Ripdog: weird "file not found" errors might be invalid character encoding related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to use tagging library you may look at [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net); then you could set utf-8 encoded tags as follows:

```
import eyeD3

tag = eyeD3.Tag ('file.mp3')
tag.setVersion (eyeD3.ID3_V2_4)
tag.setTextEncoding (eyeD3.UTF_8_ENCODING)
tag.setArtist ('artist')
tag.setAlbum ('album')
tag.setTitle ('title')
tag.update ()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately, that module does not appear to support python 3.1. I'll give it a go, but if I end up having to backport my script to 2.6, I'll probably just end up using Mutagen. Thanks again